# Existence of orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms, orbitals

Do orbitals exist even when they are not occupied?

For example: $\ce{Cr^{+3}}$ has the configuration $\ce{[Ar]}\mathrm{3d^3}$ with the other two $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals empty. We know the  other two orbitals exist, since the metal "uses its empty $\mathrm{d}$ orbitals" to form complexes.

But, for $\ce{Na+}$ with configuration $\ce{[Ne]}$, do the $\mathrm{3s,3p}$ and $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals exist  too?

Comment: click on the [edited $x$ ago](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/41309/revisions) to see that I did not touch anything that was not MathJax, thank you. (Brian is the culprit.)

Comment: @Jan Apologies.

Answer (score 7):

Do orbitals exist even when they *are* occupied? Orbitals are mathematical constructs and as such they *exist* in a mathematical sense regardless of whether they are occupied or not. Whether you can actually say that orbitals exist in reality is a bit dubious. They certainly provide a good description of the observed electron density and behaviour of atoms but they are still only a model. Like everything in science, we develop a model to *describe* what we *observe* but that model is not perfect and does not necessarily represent what actually *exists*. Particularly on a quantum scale, the notion of well defined objects that exist in space starts to become a bit fuzzy.

Comment: In that case  every atom can be thought of having  empty  orbitals.Then why do we argue this happens because this particular element has empty orbitals to accommodate the electron pair?
Empty orbitals always exist as per your answer.

Comment: @yasir Yes, they do; but what is meant is usually *accessable* empty orbitals. Example: phosphorus and sulphur have *unaccessable* $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals (they are high in energy and cannot really participate in hybridisation). A carbon-bromine bond has an *accessable* $\unicode[Times]{x3c3}^*$ orbital which can be attacked by the lone pair of a nucleophile because it is relatively *low* in energy.

Comment: @yasir By calculating (or measuring) energies or by qualified *a priori* guesses.

Comment: So for $\ce{Hg^{+2}}$ the $\ce{6d}$  orbitals are accessible?Actually it has something to do with oxymercuration demercuration mechanism, so bear with me.

Comment: @yasir - There is a finite probability that the electrons are in any number of infinite electronic states - which includes those higher energy "orbitals" - but the probability is exceptionally low in the ground state. That probability can change - higher or lower - depending on the environment (applied electric field, for instance). I'd say all the "orbitals" are accessible but some of them (the ones we see for ground state electronic configurations) are way more likely to be populated than the ones we'd expect to see populated in an excited state.

Comment: Todd is correct in that I maybe used a bad word when saying *accessable.* But @yasir no; an orbital of the same subshell of a higher shell is generally not accessable; $\ce{Hg^2+}$ is a $\mathrm{5d}$ element thus it can easily access $\mathrm{6s}$ and maybe $\mathrm{6p}$ but never $\mathrm{6d}$.